# Can't launch SBT

Tags: scala, sbt

After having installed SBT v 1.3.8 on a Win X machine, I launched it on my base. 
Then I get this error message :

```
[error] [launcher] download failed: org.slf4j#slf4j-api;1.7.25!slf4j-api.jar
[error] [launcher] error during sbt launcher: error retrieving required libraries
  (see C:\Users\et\.sbt\boot\update.log for complete log)
[error] [launcher] could not retrieve sbt 1.1.6
```

here is an extract of update.log :

> setting 'ivy.default.conf.dir' to
>   'jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/sbt/bin/sbt-launch.jar!/org/apache/ivy/core/settings'
>   impossible to define new type: class not found:
>   org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.VfsResolver in [] nor Ivy classloader
>   impossible to define new type: class not found:
>   org.apache.ivy.plugins.trigger.LogTrigger in [] nor Ivy classloader
>   impossible to define new type: class not found:
>   org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.MirroredURLResolver in [] nor Ivy
>   classloader impossible to define new type: class not found:
>   org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.SshResolver in [] nor Ivy classloader
>   impossible to define new type: class not found:
>   org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.DualResolver in [] nor Ivy classloader
>   impossible to define new type: class not found:
>   org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.IvyRepResolver in [] nor Ivy
>   classloader impossible to define new type: class not found:
>   org.apache.ivy.plugins.signer.bouncycastle.OpenPGPSignatureGenerator
>   in [] nor Ivy classloader impossible to define new type: class not
>   found: org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.JarResolver in [] nor Ivy
>   classloader impossible to define new type: class not found:
>   org.apache.ivy.ant.AntCallTrigger in [] nor Ivy classloader impossible
>   to define new type: class not found:
>   org.apache.ivy.ant.AntBuildTrigger in [] nor Ivy classloader
>   impossible to define new type: class not found:
>   org.apache.ivy.plugins.version.PatternVersionMatcher in [] nor Ivy
>   classloader impossible to define new type: class not found:
>   org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.packager.PackagerResolver in [] nor
>   Ivy classloader impossible to define new type: class not found:
>   org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.VsftpResolver in [] nor Ivy
>   classloader impossible to define new type: class not found:
>   org.apache.ivy.plugins.conflict.RegexpConflictManager in [] nor Ivy
>   classloader impossible to define new type: class not found:
>   org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.SFTPResolver in [] nor Ivy classloader
>   impossible to define new type: class not found:
>   org.apache.ivy.osgi.updatesite.UpdateSiteResolver in [] nor Ivy
>   classloader impossible to define new type: class not found:
>   org.apache.ivy.osgi.obr.OBRResolver in [] nor Ivy classloader
>   impossible to define glob matcher:
>   org.apache.ivy.plugins.matcher.GlobPatternMatcher was not found.

and here is the *build.sbt* file :

```
name := course.value + "-" + assignment.value

scalaVersion := "2.13.1"

scalacOptions ++= Seq("-deprecation")

courseId := "GVy8tIIKEeWXmQ4F86nmrw"

// grading libraries
libraryDependencies += "junit" % "junit" % "4.10" % Test
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.storm-enroute" %% "scalameter-core" % "0.6",
  "com.github.scala-blitz" %% "scala-blitz" % "1.1",
  "org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-swing" % "1.0.1",
  "com.storm-enroute" %% "scalameter" % "0.6" % Test
)

// include the common dir
commonSourcePackages += "common"
```

Subsequent attempts also fail with following error :

```
error: error while loading String, class file '/modules/java.base/java/lang/String.class' is broken
(class java.lang.NullPointerException/null)
[error] java.io.IOError: java.lang.RuntimeException: /packages cannot be represented as URI
[error]         at java.base/jdk.internal.jrtfs.JrtPath.toUri(JrtPath.java:176)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.classpath.JrtClassPath.asURLs(DirectoryClassPath.scala:204)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.classpath.AggregateClassPath.$anonfun$asURLs$1(AggregateClassPath.scala:55)
[error]         at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$flatMap$1(TraversableLike.scala:241)
[error]         at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:944)
....
```

Any help very appreciated as I'm beginner with SBT.

Comment: Can you start by moving that ```junit``` dependency into the Seq? Also note that Scala has it's own testing suites, there is no reason to use junit

Comment: What java version are you using?
Looks like compatibility issue.

Comment: I'm using v. 13.0.1

Comment: neither moving junit into the seq nor comenting out had any effect, still getting the error.

Comment: Definitely a compatibility issue. Quite a few reports like this in sbt/scala bug trackers and projects using latest jdk.
https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/5093

Comment: I tried to insatall various SDK, the only one not issuing the error is *AdoptOpenSDK* 8.  At least it moved a little bit further to next error message.  I guess I'll open another post with new error message encountered. Thanks to all that responded.